# Como ordenar un JSON en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, json

he intentado recorrer este JSON y guardarlo en array diferentes para poder agruparlo por nombre_servicio pero no lo he logrado, necesito de su ayuda si alguien sabe como, lo ideal seria poder agruparlo por nombre_servicio ya que hay algunos que se repiten.

```
rows: [
{
  id: 1123,
  nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
  nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
  valor: '6000'
},
{
  id: 1124,
  nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
  nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
  valor: '2000'
},
{
  id: 1125,
  nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR EJECUTIVO',
  nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
  valor: '4000'
},
{
  id: 1126,
  nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR GENERAL',
  nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
  valor: '50000'
},
{
  id: 1127,
  nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR TÉCNICO',
  nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
  valor: '7000'
}
```

]

Lo ideal seria poder recorrerlo y guardarlo en un array o agruparlo pero que quede esta manera o al menos similar:

```
rows: [
{
  id: 1123,
  nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
  values: [
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
    valor: '6000'
    },
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
    valor: '2000'
    },
  ]
},
{
  id: 1125,
  nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR EJECUTIVO',
  values: [
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
    valor: '0'
    },
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
    valor: '4000'
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 1126,
  nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR GENERAL',
  values: [
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
    valor: '50000'
    },
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
    valor: '0'
    }
  ]
  
},
{
  id: 1127,
  nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR TÉCNICO',
  values: [
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
    valor: '0'
    },
    {
    nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
    valor: '7000'
    }
  }
  
}
```

]

Soy principiante en el mundo de javascript y les agradeceria mucho si me ayudan con esto, quizás no es posible?

He intentado hacerlo con javascript pero nada, no hay resultado.

Dejo una de mis pruebas fracadas.

```html
let data = [
    {
      id: 1123,
      nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
      valor: '6000'
    },
    {
      id: 1124,
      nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
      valor: '2000'
    },
    {
      id: 1125,
      nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR EJECUTIVO',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
      valor: '4000'
    },
    {
      id: 1126,
      nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR GENERAL',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
      valor: '50000'
    },
    {
      id: 1127,
      nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR TÉCNICO',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
      valor: '7000'
    }

]

let values = []
let new_data = []
let valuesmask = {}
let name_service = ''
data.forEach(val => {
  if(name_service !== val.nombre_servicio){
      console.log(val.nombre_servicio)
      valuesmask = {
        nombre_valor: val.nombre_valor,
        valor: val.valor
      }
      values.push(valuesmask)
  }

  name_service = val.nombre_servicio

})

new_data.push(values)

console.log(new_data)
```

Comment: La propiedad `id` no debería estar dentro de `values`? porque hay distintos ids en `nombre_servicio` iguales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes transformar el arreglo mediante un *[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)*, este método itera el arreglo y devuelve un valor transformado según se indique en la función de transformación (*callback*).

Para este caso se puede crear un arreglo en donde se identifique via *[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)* si el servicio ya fue agregado, si lo encuentra solo agrega a los *values* el valor de la iteración actual para nombre_valor y valor; en caso de que no exista se crea un nuevo objeto en el arreglo con la representación del servicio y valor en el formato en el que se requiere.

```js
let data = [
    {
      id: 1123,
      nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
      valor: '6000'
    },
    {
      id: 1124,
      nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
      valor: '2000'
    },
    {
      id: 1125,
      nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR EJECUTIVO',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
      valor: '4000'
    },
    {
      id: 1126,
      nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR GENERAL',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
      valor: '50000'
    },
    {
      id: 1127,
      nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR TÉCNICO',
      nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
      valor: '7000'
    }

]

let grouped = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  // Encontrar la posición de este servicio en el nuevo arreglo
  let position = acc.findIndex(a => a.nombre_servicio === current.nombre_servicio)
   
  // Si no existe entonces crear una nueva entrada en el arreglo.
  if (position < 0) {
    acc.push({
      id: current.id,
      nombre_servicio: current.nombre_servicio,
      values: [
      {
        nombre_valor: current.nombre_valor,
        valor: current.valor
      }]
    })
  } else {  // Caso contrario solo agregar el valor actual a la colección values
    acc[position].values.push({
        nombre_valor: current.nombre_valor,
        valor: current.valor
    })
  }
 
  return acc
}, []) // inicializa el valor de retorno como arreglo vacío)

console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: Gracias maestro! muy util, admiro su trabajo!

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un arreglo de objetos, puedes ciclar a través de un for o foreach para comparar y agrupar o puedes utilizar el método reduce de JavaScript, el cual ejecuta una función reductora sobre cada elemento de un array, devolviendo como resultado un único valor.
[Referencia reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

En este ejemplo cree una función, en donde se pide como parámetros un arreglo y una llave o en este caso una propiedad del objeto para poder agrupar.

Después de haber agrupado, ciclamos nuestro arreglo de arreglos
es decir:
var arr=[  [ {},{}], [ {},{}], ]
por cada arreglo lo reemplazamos con un objeto y así mismo lo agregamos en una de las propiedades del objeto, podemos utilizar sort para ordenar y para identificar cada agrupamiento tomamos el primero propiedad del primer objeto ya que esta propiedad se repetirá en todos los demás.
Saludos!

```js
var datos = [
    {
        id: 1123,
        nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
        nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
        valor: '6000'
    },
    {
        id: 1124,
        nombre_servicio: 'ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN',
        nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
        valor: '2000'
    },
    {
        id: 1125,
        nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR EJECUTIVO',
        nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
        valor: '4000'
    },
    {
        id: 1126,
        nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR GENERAL',
        nombre_valor: 'Jornada 8 horas',
        valor: '50000'
    },
    {
        id: 1127,
        nombre_servicio: 'PRODUCTOR TÉCNICO',
        nombre_valor: 'Jornada 12 horas',
        valor: '7000'
    }
]


var datos_agrupados = groupBy(datos, 'nombre_servicio')

for (var i = 0; i < datos_agrupados.length; i++) {
    var values = datos_agrupados[i] 
    values = values.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
    var values_specifics = values.map((object) => {
        return {
            nombre_valor: object.nombre_valor,
            valor: object.valor
        }
    });
    this.datos_agrupados[i] = {
        nombre_servicio: this.datos_agrupados[i][0].nombre_servicio,
        values: values_specifics
    }
}

console.log(datos_agrupados)



/**funcion de agrupar */
function groupBy(array, key) {
    return Array.from(array
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[key], [...(m.get(o[key]) || []), o]), new Map)
        .values()
    );
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! pero veo que el resultado no cambia mucho al original, sera posible que "ASISTENTE PRODUCCION" aparezca una sola vez y con su correspondiente valor que seria 'Jornada 8 horas' y 'Jornada 12 horas'

Comment: Si, permíteme actualizar el código, va

Comment: vale gracias!!!

Comment: Hola. me sale un error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at fs:/src/script.js (<anonymous>:82:49)
    at __require (<anonymous>:14:50)
    at <anonymous>:103:29
    at hn (https://preview-new.playcode.io/:190:5449)

Comment: Comparte por favor tu codigo